# Как вывести код цвета в TextView? Android

Tags: java, android, textview

В программировании новичок. Пишу приложение, которое по нажатию на кнопку генерирует случайный цвет и заливает этим цветом фон. Хочу еще чтобы этот случайный цвет выводился в TextView. Но при нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает с такой ошибкой (думаю дело все-таки в ней):

> *Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""*

Ошибка в строчке: `color = Integer.parseInt(colorstring);`

Код целиком:

```
private LinearLayout mBackgroundLinearLayout;
int color;
TextView tv1;
String colorstring = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    mBackgroundLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    mBackgroundLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    color = Integer.parseInt(colorstring);
    tv1.setText(colorstring);
}
```

Comment: Так у вас же colostring = "";   В этой строке нечего парсить

Comment: Такое ощущение что автор планировал наоборот сделать colorstring= Integer.parseInt(color);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для установки:

```
tv1.setText(String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & color));
```

Уберите

```
color = Integer.parseInt(colorstring);
```

Comment: А если заместо RGB использовать ARGB, то как тогда поменяется строка: "tv1.setText(String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & color));" ?

Comment: @Semmy тогда `Integer.toHexString(color)` или String.format("#%08X", color). А можете в промежуточные переменные записывать сгенерированные значения и их использовать как угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать ваш метод onClick(); таким образом

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    mBackgroundLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    colorstring = String.valueOf(mBackgroundLinearLayout.getBackgroundColor());
    tv1.setText(colorstring);
}
```

Comment: " Cannot  resolve method 'getBackgroundColor()' " :(

Comment: Drawable background = view.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
                color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();